# Error de instalacion aplicacion .NET (GAC)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo una aplicación que se publica en un servidor y que comprueba contra ese servidor si hay una version nueva para instalarselo, hasta ahora las actualizaciones han funcionado perfectamente pero esta vez, tras añadirle una libreria .dll para generar ficheros excel me falla cuando intenta actualizar con el siguiente mensaje:

[image: Error de GAC]

Agradeceria que alguien me indique que he de hacer para que al publicarlo se publique correctamente y que los usuarios al actualizar no reciban este error.
La version de Visual Studio es las de 2005
Gracias.

Comment: Entiendo que el problema reside en que la librería para generar ficheros excel tiene dependencia del `VSTOStorageWrapper.Interop` y que no puede resolverla. La forma de resolver esto es tremendamente amplia, no obstante, diría que lo suyo sería que implementaras una lógica que evalúe si la dependencia se cumple antes de instalarse.

Comment: Prueba a ir a las propiedades del proyecto, pestaña "Publicar" (desde donde publicas normalmente la aplicacion. Revisa en "Requisitos previos" si te aparece esa libreria y marcala en "Elegir los requisitos previos que se van a instalar". Si no te funciona nos lo comentas

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, finalmente he encontrado que es propiedades de proyecto -> Application Files donde hay que añadirlo, lo pongo como solución por si a alguien mas le pasa no se vuelva loco/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente la solución es tan sencilla como que en propiedades de proyecto -> Application Files  hay que ponerlo como Include y (Required)